# Are any of the GNOME themes customizable?

Tags: icons, themes

I'm trying to understand why I can no longer create custom icons for my folders and files in Bionic Beaver (18.04). Q: Do any of the GNOME themes allow one to use custom icons, especially for folders and shortcuts on the desktop? In Unity, one could simply right-click a folder and have numerous options available to replace or resize its individual icon. Is this feature gone in GNOME?

Here is my old Unity desktop with custom icons.
[image: Here is my old Unity desktop with custom icons.]

Comment: Same thing (right-click a folder and select custom image for icon from properties) can be done in GNOME, not working for you?

Comment: No right click in 18.04 on my notebook, nautilus got removed from the desktop. 2 finger tap of touchpad opens context menu. No properties though. Gnome developers do not want us to have desktop icons ... they consider it a nuisance it seems; there will be an extension for it. with all the options,

Comment: @Rinzwind It's true that GNOME developers got rid of desktop icons from Nautilus 3.28, but Ubuntu developers shipped Bionic with Nautilus 3.26 instead of 3.28 just to provide the feature. If you don't see desktop icons, check in GNOME Tweaks > Desktop. "Show Icons" options may be disabled.

Comment: Hi, Pomsky. Yes, I've right-clicked the folder, clicked PROPERTIES, clicked the folder icon, navigated to my desired icon, and clicked OK. Nothing happens. It was all so easy in Unity. Not so much now. The second I upgraded to 17.10, actually, all my custom folder icons reverted to generic folder icons.